# How to get a Preference to display custom items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

In my preferences.xml file I can display texts, checkboxes, and lists, but what if I want to display something that doesn't have a built-in category, like a Calendar or Time object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own classes extending `Preference`.
They can be used in a preference xml.

Comment: Do you have a basic example I can reference? I'm trying to include a Calendar item in my preferences.xml as a test of this functionality